# Do experience counters remain when the card creating them leaves the battlefield?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For example, my [Mizzix of the Izmagnus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMizzix%20of%20the%20Izmagnus%5d) created two experience counters but then gets destroyed. What happens to the counters? Do they leave as well, or stay?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you keep the experience counters if Mizzix leaves the battlefield.

Mizzix's ability says

> Whenever you cast an instant or sorcery spell with converted mana cost greater than the number of experience counters you have, **you get an experience counter**.

The counters go on you, the player, rather than on any other object. When creatures die that has no effect on counters on players.